# Class Generics method definition

Tags: java, generics

Assuming that you have a lot of classes that `extends` the class `Base`.

```
class Base{}

class A extends Base[}

class B extends Base{}

class C extends Base{}
```

What must I write so that when I write a get method, I will get the class that I want?

```
public Base get(Class <? extends Base> clazz, final String key){
    //not important.
}
```

I want the method to return Objects of `class` `A`, `B`, or `C`, depending on the input `clazz`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T extends Base> T get(Class<T> clazz, final String key) {
}
```

is closer to what you need.  Keep in mind that during method declared generic variables, to have more success you typically put the modifiers outside of the parameter list.

Comment: Thanks Tom, in my hurry I forgot to add it.